# Which part of memory, Loadable Kernel Modules are Residing?

Tags: linux-kernel

Are LKMs in linux OS residing in dynamic part of memory (heap or .bss) or are staying as static code in the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory for modules is allocated via vmalloc

Comment: So it is part of dynamic memory (e.g heap). Thanks!.

Comment: You never know which and how many of them will be insmoded, so this couldn't be done in static